# Split character Reporting Service (Character "ENTER")

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

i had one row from database
when i view this data on reporting service i get view:

baris 1
baris 2

i want to change view on reporting service to be

1. baris 1
2. baris 2

anyone can help please?

Comment: you can add [RowNumber()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159225%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) in your report with spit the data.

Comment: can you share more detail to split this?

Comment: here is the link for the split the string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/tsql-split-string

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of the Split function with the constant: Constants.vbCrLf.  In your scenario the Split might be tricky - there's no obvious delimiter to split on.

This example might get you started:

= "1. " + Split ( Fields!my_column.Value , " " )(0) + " " + Split ( Fields!my_column.Value , " " )(1) 
+ Constants.vbCrLf 
+ "2. " + Split ( Fields!my_column.Value , " " )(2) + " " + Split ( Fields!my_column.Value , " " )(3)